# Setting up iptables for a hostapd wifi login page

Tags: iptables

I need some custom iptables for a login page of my wifi hotspot on my raspberry pi. I want an http login page: this is how it should work, I just don't know how to configure the iptables.:

Any connections on an ip address that is not already logged in, should be redirected to the pi's port 8181 (the server for my login page).

Any connections on an ip address that is logged in should be allowed to access the outside internet.

Any connections initially requesting the pi's port 8181 should be allowed.

How should I set this up with `iptables`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've found the following article very helpful when learning iptables:

http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/IPTables

Basically you can start with a something similar to:

```
# iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
# iptables -F
# iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
# iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
# iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
# iptables -P INPUT DROP
# iptables -P FORWARD DROP
# iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

This will block pretty much everything other than SSH, outgoing connections, and connections that are previously established (ie from previous outgoing connections)

Once that is in place you need to do the redirection:
http://proghowto.com/iptables-redirect-port-80-to-port-8080

And finally you need to run something like the following for each ip that gets authenticated:

```
# iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.0.4 -j ACCEPT
```